# .Net Core 5 SignalR Simultaneous connections hold (Ef Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have a method like this on the SignalR hub side.

```
public async Task EmailRegister (string email) {
   var anyUser = _dbContext.User.Any (x => x.Email == email);
   if (! anyUser) return;

   var newUser = new User {Email = email};

   _dbContext.User.Add (newUser);
   _dbContext.SaveChanges ();

   Clients.All.SendAsync ("InitComplete", newUser);
}
```

The problem I experience is when more than one request comes to this method at the same time.

Before the first request is completed n. Since the request came, the same record occurs n times.

I just wrote the above method as an example, the actual method is much more complicated.

The Any control at the beginning returns false for 2 consecutive requests, since no new user has been created yet.

As such, the same record occurs 2 times.

Comment: If possible, you can try to create a unique constraint on the "Email" column in your database.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. As I said, there are some more complex queries in this section. Email is a value that I give just as an example.